# R - Extracting a reference object from a string?

Tags: r

In R, I have a list that looks something like this:

```
x <- list(`1`=1, `2`=2, `3`=3)
```

and a variable like this:

```
a = '`1`'
```

and I need to somehow access the list from the variable, like this:

```
b = x$a
```

but the above obviously won't work because the variable "a" is a string.

Is there any way to do this? I'm not too familiar with R data types, and I've tried browsing ?Extract, and ?"`" but haven't had much success.

I'm getting these variables in this format from a 3rd party and I have no control over them, but I need to work with them somehow.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `x[[a]]`? Double brackets should be covered in `?Extract`.

Comment: I tried in my terminal, and x[[a]] gives NULL as a result. Thanks, though.

Comment: So either you've mistakenly placed the backticks in your character variable, in which case the double brackets works fine. Otherwise, your actual problem is that you just have weird inputs that you need to remove the backticks from, maybe with `gsub`.

Answer (score 1):

`x[['1']]` works, but you're calling `` x[['`1`']] ``

```
x <- list(`1`=1, `2`=2, `3`=3)
a = '`1`'

# doesn't work, bc the first element is named "1" not "`1`"
x[[a]]

# works fine
other_a = '1'
x[[other_a]]
```

Here's an example that takes away the backticks/quote thing, which is what's confounding you

```
x <- list(apple=1, banana=2)
a = 'orange'

# this doesn't work, just as you'd expect -- returns null because there's no such element
x[[a]] 

other_a = 'apple'

# this works fine, and gets you the value of the element named apple
x[[other_a]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have no control over the value of the variable "a". That's my problem. The value of a = '`1`' in my case.

Comment: I think you are getting mixed up by the backticks -- you are looking for a named element of the list x that just isn't present, but when you use a name that _is_ present it all works. See updated answer for illustration that may help clear it up